# Как вывести на экран содержание определённых файлов?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Как вывести на экран содержание определённых файлов, у которых в названии 1-ые символы "*part*"? Файлы со следующими именами: "*part-m-00000*", "*part-m-00001*", "*part-m-00002*".., имена всех начинаются с "*part*", и их содержание нужно вывести на экран, помимо этих файлов есть и другие с другими названиями, не начинающиеся на "*part*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если надо просто подряд (слитно) только содержимое (без имен и т.п.) всех файлов, начинающихся на part то:

```
cat part*
```

`*` в именах заменяет любые символы, `?` - один любой символ

Comment: то, что надо! спасибо. а где можно по-подробнее почитать об этом?

Comment: Ну вот, например http://citforum.ru/programming/shell/index.shtml   собственно гугл по запросу `команды shell` неплохую выборку дает, прямо несколько первых ссылок можно читать

Comment: @Mike: у каждого свои несколько первых ссылок ))

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант.

Для поставленной задачи `ls` избыточен, но в общем и целом дает больше возможностей отфильтровать список файлов.

`less` позволит нам читать содержимое постепенно и перелистывать его вверх и вниз.

```
cat $(ls part*) | less
```

Если список файлов очень большой и вам нужно искать по регулярному выражению, то используйте grep (egrep) на выводе команды ls. `ls -1` выводит имя каждого файла в новой строке.

```
cat $(ls -1 | grep 'part|shmart|parabart') | less
```